Compute weighted quantile with duckdb on R
I would like to compute the weighted median of a variable on R.
Due to the size of my dataset, I need to use duckdb.
I did this :

library(nycflights13) #dataset example
library("Hmisc") # for the function wtd.quantile

con <- dbConnect(duckdb())


duckdb_register(con, "flights", nycflights13::flights)
colnames(flights)

tbl(con, "flights") %>% 
  summarise(.by = dest,
            delay = median(dep_time, na.rm = T))

tbl(con, "flights") %>% 
  summarise(.by = dest,
            wg.delay = wtd.quantile(dep_time, weights = distance, type = "quantile"))


I receive this error :
Error in collect(): ! Failed to collect lazy table. Caused by error: ! Parser Error: syntax error at or near "AS" LINE 3:   wtd.quantile(dep_time, distance AS weights, 'quantile' A...
Could anyone help me ?

You forgot a few library calls, so let's partially rewrite it:
library(nycflights13) #dataset example
library(duckdb)
library("Hmisc") # for the function wtd.quantile
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
con <- dbConnect(duckdb())


duckdb_register(con, "flights", nycflights13::flights)
colnames(flights)

tbl(con, "flights") %>%
  summarise(.by = dest,
            delay = median(dep_time, na.rm = T)) %>%
  show_query()

I added a show_query() to your first working example.
<SQL>
SELECT dest, PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY dep_time) AS delay
FROM flights
GROUP BY dest

This is some magic in dbplyr (note the b for dataBase). It or its programmers know how to translate mean(), and it's quite a bit different from your median.
Now think of the rather complex wtd.quantile, which is an R function. There is no easy translation to SQL for it, so the parser does strange things (it even hung for me).
One non-solution would be to use collect() in between. It works, but it forces a read into memory, so your duck is crying for the meaning of life.
I had to add a drop_na because of some missing values, and there is a depreciation warning, as so often in the tidyverse.
tt = tbl(con, "flights") %>%
  collect()  %>%
  tidyr::drop_na()  %>%
  summarise(.by = dest,
    wg.delay = wtd.quantile(dep_time, weights = distance, type = "quantile")) 

